# Google Analytics V4 Not showing data

Tags: android, google-analytics

I did as the example

```
Hello World Android app
```

in my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- Google Analytics required permissions -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<!-- Optional permission for reliable local dispatching on non-Google Play devices -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />




<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
    android:name=".MyApp">


    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>


    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- Enable background dispatching to improve delivery on non-Google Play devices -->
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsReceiver"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.ANALYTICS_DISPATCH"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false"/>

    <!-- Enable Google Play Store Campaign reports -->
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service
  android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingService"
        android:enabled="true"/>
</application>
```

and I have the MyApp as normal but every time I run the app these messages appear and I cant see and thing in analytics/web/

> 07-22 17:19:47.506  20695-20695/? W/GAv4﹕ AnalyticsReceiver is not registered or is disabled. Register the receiver for reliable dispatching on non-Google Play devices. See [google link] for instructions.
>
> 07-22 17:19:47.546  20695-20695/? W/GAv4﹕ CampaignTrackingReceiver is not registered, not exported or is disabled. Installation campaign tracking is not possible. See [google link] for instructions.
>
> 07-22 17:19:47.546  20695-20722/? W/GAv4﹕ AnalyticsService not registered in the app manifest. Hits might not be delivered reliably. See [google link] for instructions.

## FIXED

**I dont know what happened I just took a rest and all things were fine**

Comment: Have you set TrackingID properly. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/37827975/3496570 and these are simple warning. These reciever aren't necessary. If you want to track screen screen only. No need to add them